# Convert to Microsoft azure cloud service project disabled in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, azure

I followed below link to publish my web-app in Azure.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-hybrid-app-using-service-bus-relay/

After creating ASP.NET MVC application, I tried to convert the project to Microsoft azure cloud service project disabled in visual studio. But `Microsoft azure cloud service project disabled in visual studio` option is disabled in my visual studio. Am I missing anything here?

```
RightClick on project ------> convert---> microsoft azure cloud service project disabled in visual studio
```

Here `Microsoft azure cloud service project` option is disabled in visual studio is disabled. What configuration do i need to do to enable it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you in debug mode?